# Lyx changed format from usepackage{} to use_package

Tags: lyx, syntax

My document was written in the following syntax with LyX:
\usepackage{algorithm}
then everything in the document change to (I don't know how...):
\use_package algorithm 1
instead...

Do you know how can i return the format to \usepackage{algorithm}?

This is the old Lyx file:

```
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble




\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package none
\inputencoding utf8x
\fontencoding T1
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 11
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 2
\use_package amssymb 2
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 0
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 0
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\end_body
\end_document
```

---

This is the new one:

```
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: In the LyX file? They are not LaTeX files, so they have a different syntax

Comment: When you export the LyX file to LaTeX,   `\use_package algorithm 1`  will produce `\usepackage{algorithm}`, so this never will be a a problem ... unless you want to load a package with some options, but it was already loaded automatically by LyX without options (or with another options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample `.lyx` file created by LyX 2.3:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
This is a sample document.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Let's focus on this:

```
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
```

The first entry sets a boolean condition to not use the [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. That is because LyX has a built-in option for setting the page geometry (margins) via Document > Settings...:

[image]

If you leave the default option checked, LyX will set

```
\use_geometry false
```

If you change any of the margins, you'll note

```
\use_geometry true
```

in the `.lyx` file. Now focus on the second entry

```
\use_package amsmath 1
```

This is another internal setting that allows LyX to provide menu options for environments (and macros) that relate to certain external packages

[image]

For example, you don't have add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble if you use the `align` environment. Instead, LyX adds this automatically if you use it, and excludes it if you don't. Here's a live preview of the LaTeX Preamble during the insertion/removal of an `align` environment:

[image]

So, the `\use_package` format as internal and specific to packages with built-in elements that forms part of the LyX interface. You can still use `\usepackage{<pkg>}` in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble if you want to use a certain package (and/or macros/environments).